# Handling iPad Shake Gesture

Tags: html, ipad, shake, adobe-dps

I would like to know how to detect the shake gesture on an iPad and make it cause a animation on a digital publication page (ex: image changes).  I am using Adobe DPS at the moment and considering MagPlus as well.  I am a total newbie to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using webviews in you magazine. In the webview you can use the HTML5 orientation api to listen to the event. Or you can use a javascript plugin called [Shake.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js).